# Is creating a new plugin necessary when creating a custom widget in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, widget

I am following a tutorial on creating a custom widget and it is doing it by placing it into a new custom plugin.

My question is the next: do I actually need/ is advisable to create a custom plugin to create the custom widget?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a widget in either a THEME or PLUGIN.

If you think there will be a need to keep the data in the widget while changing to a different theme, then it should be a plugin. If the widget is very specific to your theme, then it should stay with the theme.

Comment: Relevant: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/12615)